# How can I fix Kotlin Overload Resolution Ambiguity with extension functions and type bounds

Tags: kotlin, generics

I want to define an Option type, and then pseudo-polymorphically define a `getOrNull` operation.

```
sealed interface Option<out T>
data class Some<out T>(val value: T): Option<T>
object None: Option<Nothing>

fun <T> Option<T>.getOrNull(): T? = when (this) {
    is Some<T> -> getOrNull()
    is None -> getOrNull()
}

fun <T> Some<T>.getOrNull(): T = value
fun None.getOrNull(): Nothing? = null
```

This all works fine.

But if I tighten the generic type to disallow `Option(null)` by specifying `T: Any`

```
fun <T: Any> Option<T>.getOrNull(): T? = when (this) {
    is Some<T> -> getOrNull()
    is None -> getOrNull()
}
```

then I get

```
Kotlin: Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public fun <T : Any> Option<TypeVariable(T)>.getOrNull(): TypeVariable(T)? defined in root package in file Delme.kt
public fun <T> Some<TypeVariable(T)>.getOrNull(): TypeVariable(T) defined in root package in file Delme.kt
```

for the line `is Some<T> -> getOrNull()`

How can I tell the compiler which of the two subclass extension functions it should be calling?

Comment: Why not just use nullable types, though? They provide nice syntax and are natively supported by the language

Comment: Oh absolutely. This just came up on Reddit and puzzled me https://www.reddit.com/r/Kotlin/comments/xewhsc/psa_static_polymorphism_with_extension_functions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, when you constrain the T of `Option<T>.getOrNull` but NOT the `T` of `Some<T>.getOrNull` you take away the fact that one was more specific than the other (a subtype). Now, they are just "different", hence the resolution ambiguity (the compiler cannot "order" them by specificity anymore).

You can solve it by also constraining `Some<T>.getOrNull` with `Any`:

```kotlin
fun <T : Any> Some<T>.getOrNull(): T = value
```

Comment: Ah, stupid of me, obvious when you see it.